# Arduino MQTT synchronicity

Tags: arduino, wifi, mqtt, robotics

I try to establish a MQTT-connection between Arduino WifiRev2  and
a python script on an ubuntu20-system.

For test purposes the arduino is connected with 3 ultrasonic sensors and a gyro sensor.

The mqtt-connection seems to work fine, arduino does publish the sensor data and
also receives commands from the python scripts.

But the sensor data are not sent synchronously.
The sensor sent first is received much more frequent (about faktor 4)
than the other sensor data.

The script is adopted from this example code:
https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-wifi-rev2/uno-wifi-r2-mqtt-device-to-device

Here is the loop in my arduino script:

```
const long interval = 30;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
void loop() {

  mqttClient.poll();

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time a message was sent
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    //record random value from A0, A1 and A2
    //int Rvalue = analogRead(A0);
    int gyroSCL = digitalRead(gryoSCL_PIN);
    int gyroSDA = digitalRead(gryoSDA_PIN);
    int l_distance = getUSensDistance(USens_L_Trig_Pin,USens_L_Echo_Pin);
    int r_distance = getUSensDistance(USens_R_Trig_Pin,USens_R_Echo_Pin);
    int f_distance = getUSensDistance(USens_F_Trig_Pin,USens_F_Echo_Pin);
    int g_value = getGyro();

    mqttClient.beginMessage(topicL);
    mqttClient.print(l_distance);
    mqttClient.endMessage();

    mqttClient.beginMessage(topicR);
    mqttClient.print(r_distance);
    mqttClient.endMessage();

    mqttClient.beginMessage(topicF);
    mqttClient.print(f_distance);
    mqttClient.endMessage();

    mqttClient.beginMessage(topicG);
    mqttClient.print(g_value);
    mqttClient.endMessage();

    //Serial.println();
  }
}
```

The python script is based on this example:
https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-python

A print example from the python subscriber is like this:

```
Connected to MQTT Broker!
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 678024
Received `25` from `usens_f` topic (timeDiff: 882899
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 87380
Received `49` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 274183
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 501763
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 702241
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 911118
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 113206
Received `44` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 316174
Received `45` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 521477
Received `45` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 725778
Received `45` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 930363
Received `-1` from `gyro` topic (timeDiff: 135167
Received `45` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 354054
Received `54` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 647140
Received `42` from `usens_r` topic (timeDiff: 647306
Received `41` from `usens_r` topic (timeDiff: 852423
Received `55` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 58828
Received `55` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 261107
Received `55` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 465823
Received `55` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 671458
```

So obviously some sensor data are not sent (or not received).
I tried with different intervals, but in any case it seems
that usens_l is receveid much more frequent than the other data.

There could be a more simple way to send the data synchronously
but building a string or calculate to a single value to integrate
the data and send at once. Maybe this is the solution for
my current issue. But I would like to understand, why this
communication does not work as expected.

Thank you for some hints!

Answer (score 0):

O.k., I found the solution, it was far more easy than expected:

I just had to install a local mosquitto server (as ubuntu service), now the  log looks like this:

```
Received `49` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 305325
Received `82` from `usens_r` topic (timeDiff: 305449
Received `16` from `usens_f` topic (timeDiff: 307354
Received `-1` from `gyro` topic (timeDiff: 309461
Received `49` from `usens_l` topic (timeDiff: 334474
Received `82` from `usens_r` topic (timeDiff: 337135
Received `16` from `usens_f` topic (timeDiff: 337257
Received `-1` from `gyro` topic (timeDiff: 339283
```